# training large dataset using keras-flow-from-dataframe generator

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, training-data

What is the best way to train large data-set on google Co-laboratory using keras?

size of data: 3GB images stored on Google drive.

After searching, the problem is that data didn't fetch on memory. The suggested solution in all of the articles I read was to use keras generators (as per what I understand, its role is to fetch a batch and train it, then goes to then next batch.. so on, so no need to fetch the whole data on memory at once).

I tried keras-flow-from-dataframe generator. But it didn't solve the problem and I'm still suffering from (Runtime Died)

```
train_paths = pd.read_csv(path) 

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,
samplewise_std_normalization=True,
rotation_range=30,
validation_split=0.25)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_paths,directory= None,x_col='path',y_col='label',
    subset="training",has_ext=True,
    batch_size=32,target_size =(224,224),
    color_mode= "rgb",seed=0,
    shuffle=False,class_mode="binary",drop_duplicates=False)

def compile_and_train(model, num_epochs): 
  adam =  Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=10, amsgrad=False)
  model.compile(optimizer= adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])

  filepath = 'tmp/weights/' + model.name + '.{epoch:02d}-{loss:.2f}.hdf5'
  checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)      

      STEP_SIZE_TRAIN= (train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size)+1
      STEP_SIZE_VALID= (valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size)+1
 Model_history=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,validation_data=valid_generator,validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint, tensor_board],class_weight=[1])
              return  Model_history
MobileNet_Model= MobileNet_model(input_shape)
MobileNet_model_his= compile_and_train(MobileNet_Model, num_epochs=1)
```

One suggested solution is to divide the data manually(or by for loop), save the weights after each MAJOR BATCH and continue training them for the next batch...

A question here, should I save the model(architecture) or the weights only ? And is there any better solutions instead of (for loop)? and why using keras generators don't solve this problem at all!!?

Comment: Please describe the problem fully, including source code and any errors you have got.

Comment: Thanks for response.Edited. No error, just Runtime Died.